# Authentication issue when integrating an ASP Web API app to ThinkTecture server 2.0

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, federated-identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I am working on an ASP Web API. I am integrating it to ThinkTecture Server v2.0 (which I have configured locally). For a moment I thought I had it well configured, because I added the [Authorize] attribute to the home controller and my API redirected me to the STS, then I entered my credentials and then I was redirected back to my Web API. But then I created a controller in a different folder (/api/TheController), and when I call (I am authenticated at this point) an action in this controller I am receiving an "Authorization has been denied for this request" message.

I noticed that when I call the Home controller the User.Identity is authenticated, but it is not when I call the other controller (the one in the other folder).

Any ideas what the issue might be?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In any case - APIs shouldn't do redirects. I am guessing you configured WS-Federation - this is for web applications not APIs (e.g. the system.identityModel.services config section).

For APIs you need to look into OAuth. Check the IdentityServer samples and wiki.